# IBMDB2 select query for millions of data

Tags: db2

i am new at db2 i want to select around 2 million data with single query like that
which will select and display first 5000 data and in back process it will select other 5000 data and keep on same till end of the all data help me out with this how to write query or using function

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want what's known as blocking.  However, this isn't actually handled (not the way you're thinking of) at the database level - it's handled at the application level.  You'd need to specify your platform and programming language for us to help there.  Although if you're expecting somebody to actually *read* 2 million rows, it's going to take a while...  At one row a second, that's 23 straight days.

The *reason* that SQL doesn't really perform this 'natively' is that it's (sort of) less efficient.  Also, SQL is (by design) set up to operate over the *entire* set of data, both conceptually and syntactically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the new features, that incorporates paging from Oracle or MySQL: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/limit_offset?lang=en

At the same time, you can influence the optimizer by indicating OPTIMIZED FOR n ROWS, and FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY. If you are going to read only, it is better to specify this clause in the query "FOR READ ONLY", this will increase the concurrency, and the cursor will not be update-able. Also, assign a good isolation level, for this case you could eventually use "uncommitted read" (with UR). A Previous Lock table will be good.

Do not forget the common practices like: index or cluster index, retrieve only the necessary columns, etc. and always analyze the access plan via the Explain facility.